# tweepy json getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: json, pandas, tweepy

I have collected some 12,000 tweets following the code of http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

The problem is that I get error once the tweets are higher in number. The smaller number doesn't give this problem.

```
#adding columns
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data)[["text", "lang", "created_at", "user.time_zone", "user.location"]]
```

This gives me such result

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-19596361d3f0> in <module>()
      1 #adding columns
      2 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
----> 3 tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data)[["text", "lang", "created_at", "user.time_zone",                                     "user.location"]]

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix)
    713             # TODO: handle record value which are lists, at least error
    714             #       reasonably
--> 715             data = nested_to_record(data)
    716         return DataFrame(data)
    717     elif not isinstance(record_path, list):

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in nested_to_record(ds, prefix, level)
    612 
    613         new_d = copy.deepcopy(d)
--> 614         for k, v in d.items():
    615             # each key gets renamed with prefix
    616             if level == 0:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Is there any way to get out of this I am totally a novice in handling Pandas and Json stuff.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can post some actual sample data that reproduces the problem exactly (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to best do this).  At what quantity, exactly, does your code stop working?  It's possible you're running into pagination issues if your code works with very small batches, I've had that issue with Twitter API data before.

Comment: This is clearly an issue with your `tweet_data`, and until that gets fixed, not a json or pandas error.

Comment: {tweet_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweet_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue}
this my tweet_data code